# Использование Settings которое в Properties

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Снова доброго времени суток.
Вопрос такой, нормальна ли практика использования Settings которое находится внутри Properties
У кого была какая практика использования данной фичи, и как, или где лучше сохранять свои настройки приложения?

Comment: Все зависит от целей. Если приложение портативное, то использовать стандартные настройки бессмысленно, ибо они лезут в системные директории. Если приложению нужно сохранять некий "кастомный" вид объекта, то тоже не очень хорошо подходит, ибо `Properties` отлично работают со стандартными типами, а вот свой объект засунуть геморно. Если нужно отслеживать изменения в настройках, то и тут есть свои нюансы. Короче для сааамого простейшего проекта, вполне, а если нужно чуть больше, то лучше писать свой функционал или использовать стороннее. Из стороннего могу посоветовать `Config.Net`.

Comment: Хорошо, чуть-чуть разьясню свой вопрос, я хочу в данных настройках держать вот такие вот данные: 1) Папка которую использует Пользователей для файлов 2) Версия программы 3) 2 или больше переменные типа bool, для этих целей, подойдёт это дело?

Comment: Ну если это стандартные типы и вас не смущает тот факт, что настройки будут не пойми где в системе (а если быть точнее, то в AppData) и тот факт, что нужно постоянно с проектом тащить app.Config, ну и если вам нравиться как используются данные настройки, то без проблем, используйте. Я например разрабатываю всегда портативные приложения, мне важен минимализм и что бы был удобный доступ ко всем настройкам через файл, также я использую IoC, а под него стандартный функционал настроек не очень удобен, по этому для меня `Properties` не подходит, как для вас - решать только вам.

Comment: Базовые настройки, такие как текущий язык приложения, стартовое положение и состояние окна, местоположение пользовательских настроек - я храню в реестре `HKCU/Software/MyAppName/`. А все остальное, в том числе настройки пользователя, которые он может заполнять от руки (такое не рекомендуется в реестре хранить), я просто из класса с данными настроек сериализую в JSON и записываю в файл, расположенный по умолчанию в `%APPDATA%`, но пользователю разрешено изменить его местоположение.